# Portaudio select input device for capturing

Tags: ubuntu, audio, debian, alsa, portaudio

I face some problems with set up input device for portaudio. 
I have 2 cards 0 and 1, and I want to configure: 
card 0 for capturing, card 1 for playing.

So, I edit `asound.conf` like this:

```
pcm!.default 
{
    type asym
    playback.pcm "plughw:1"
    capture.pcm "plughw:0"
}
```

I realize portaudio can not record audio file, it's always 0 byte in record file. In case of doesn't have `asound.conf` in path /etc/, Portaudio works fine. So, my question is:
How can I choose input device for portaudio between 2 cards?

Attached is my cards:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpAbw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pa_GetDeviceCount() and Pa_GetDeviceInfo() to iterate and list your devices. There is an example for doing so [here](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/group__examples__src.html), the one named pa_devs.c.

With this example you can identify the index of the device and use it depending on your needs.